# Cannot Adapt BackgroundWorker progress percentage to the real percentage of the task

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, backgroundworker

I wrote a program that reads a short video then writes the couple hundred frames with reduced FPS. It worked fine, but the "if" loop was blocking the UI. I tried to create a backgroudWorker to handle the "if" Loop , while the UI values could be displayed and the process could be interrupted by a "Cancel" button.
My problem is: I cannot make the "if" loop go through all the frames in:

```
for (i = 0; i < frames_number; i++)
```

to the last frame! it stops at 100, even though I tried multiple solutions to convert the  progress of "i" to percentage like:

```
progress = System::Convert::ToInt32((100*(i / frames_number)));
```

or

```
progress = (int)((float)i / (float)frames_number *100);
```

Here are the important snippets of the code:

```
private: System::Void CreateSlowMo_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        VideoCapture inputVideo(videoToOpenNameStr);
        if (!inputVideo.isOpened()) {
            MessageBox::Show(L"Error"); 
        }       
        fps =   int(inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FPS)); // get the frame rate of the video
        frames_number = int(inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));     // get the total frames in the video
        this->progressBar1->Maximum = frames_number;      // Initilize the progress bar's maximum to the number of frames       
        outputVideo.open(name, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps_wanted, resolution, true);  // Create an output video 
        if (outputVideo.isOpened())
        {   
            this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync(progress);     // Delegating the blocking operations to the background worker        
        }
        else {
            MessageBox::Show(L"Error creating the video");
            CreateSlowMo_button->Enabled = true;
        }       
    }
```

backgroundWorker1_DoWork:

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {

    progress = (int)e->Argument; // get the intial value of the argument
    for (i = 0; i < frames_number; i++)
    {    
        inputVideo >> source; // read frame 

        if (backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending) {   // check if the User clicked on "Cancel"
            e->Cancel = true;
            break;    // Stop the convertion
        }
        if (source.empty()) { // we reached the last frame
            break;
            //  CreateSlowMo_button->Enabled = true;
        }    
        if (progress > 100) 
        { // verify we didn't exceed 100% of the task
            backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(100);
            break;
        }       
        outputVideo << source; // write the frame to the output video
        progress = (int)(((float)i / (float)frames_number)* 100);
        backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(progress);        
    }     
    this->backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(100);
    e->Result = progress;    
}
```

backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged:

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {
    this->progressBar1->Value = e->ProgressPercentage;
    toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Processing..." + progressBar1->Value.ToString() + "%";
    richTextBox6->Text = e->ProgressPercentage.ToString();  
}
```

backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted:

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e) {
     // in case the background process is finished with a cancel
    if (e->Cancelled) 
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Task Cancelled";
    }
    // check if an error occurred in the backgroud process
    else if (e->Error != nullptr)
    { 
        toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Error while creating the SlowMo";
    }
    else 
    {   // task completed normally
        this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "SlowMo Created successfully!";
        this->cancel_button->Enabled = false;
        MessageBox::Show(L"Finished creating the sloMo");
        this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Done";
        this->CreateSlowMo_button->Enabled = true;   
        this->richTextBox5->Text = "value " + e->Result;
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots from the resulats (I added text boxes to visualise the values of 'i', 'progress' and  e->result) 'i' and 'progress' are int=0, definded in files 'variables.h'

```
extern int i ;
extern int progress;
```

and 'variables.cpp':

```
int i = 0;
int progress =0;
```

[image: UI when backgroundWorker done]

[image: UI when backgroundWorker done]

Comment: There is an obvious bug in your code, you are calculating progress from 0..100 but the ProgressBar::Maximum is not 100.  The simple workaround is to delete the `this->progressBar1->Maximum = frames_number;` assignment.

Comment: I changed it, but it effected only the progressBar (it was fully green) and couldn't go through all the frames (here 589).
Here are the results:
http://i.imgur.com/H6rP9xZ.png

http://i.imgur.com/wYAYKSO.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of `frames_number`? Or if any of your `if` statements within the `for` loop becomes true anytime during the execution?

I'm suspecting `frames_number` gets an incorrect value prior to the `for` loop, or `source.empty()` becomes true.